# JPA 2.1 @SqlResultSetMapping binding inner class to targetclass

Tags: java-8, jpa-2.1

is it possible to map inner classes to the `targetclass`, if possible, how is it done ? I'm new to this `@SqlResultSetMapping` functionality:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "EventSurveysMapping",
        classes = {
                @ConstructorResult(
                        targetClass = Survey.class,
                        columns = {
                                @ColumnResult(name = "surveyid", type = Long.class),
                        })
        })
```

So the `targetClass` `Survey.class` has:

```
public class Survey {
    private Long surveyid;
    private List<SurveyQuestion> surveyquestions;
// constructor with mapped fields
}
```

How would I map the `List<SurveyQuestion>` field ?

SurveyQuestion:

```
public class SurveyQuestion {
    private Long surveyquestionid;
    private String surveyquestion;
    private List<String> surveyanswers;
}
```

Also, and very similar. How would I map a `List<String>` ?

I get an exception when trying to do mapping to `List.class`:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "EventPollsMapping",
        classes = {
                @ConstructorResult(
                        targetClass = Poll.class,
                        columns = {
                                @ColumnResult(name="pollid", type = Long.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name="questionid", type = Long.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name="pollquestion", type = String.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name="pollanswers", type = List.class) // this mapping is the cause of the exception
                        })
        })
```

*Exception:*

> org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException Exception
>   Description: The object [It is Primary ID, It is unique ID], of class
>   [class java.lang.String], could not be converted to [interface
>   java.util.List]

Poll:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType (propOrder={"pollid",
"pollquestionid",
"pollquestion",
"pollanswers"
})
public class Poll {
    private Long pollid;
    private Long pollquestionid;
    private String pollquestion;
    private List<String> pollanswers;


    public Poll(){}

    public Poll(Long pollid, Long pollquestionid, String pollquestion, List<String> pollanswers) {
        super();
        this.pollid = pollid;
        this.pollquestionid = pollquestionid;
        this.pollquestion = pollquestion;
        this.pollanswers = pollanswers;
    }

// setters & getters 
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code of `Poll` class + the relative mappings used for  `Survey` and `SurveyQuestion`?

Comment: Just to clarify, the impl.  is  EclipseLink not Hibernate.

Comment: @O.Badr, added Poll class. Mapping for survey and surveyquestions is already there.

Comment: Can you give the query used for mapping to the target class (e.g. `EventSurveysMapping`) ?

Comment: I have a similar requirement. Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: @CharveeShah,  whoa, truth be told, I don't remember. I think I just used plain JDBC, but le me check

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, When I had to map a Collection of things, finally I did something like this:

```
@OneToMany
private Set<SurveyQuestion> surveyanswers;
```

All of this if you're using an extension of your JPA provider supporting collection of basic types. (e.g. Hibernate has the @CollectionOfElements annotation).

Comment: Hibernate [@CollectionOfElements](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/CollectionOfElements.html) is replaced by [@ElementCollection](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this doesn't have much to do with my question, `@ConstructorResult` is used with NON entities.